# apache not working in ubuntu 14.04 Plesk server getting syntax error

Tags: ubuntu, apache2, ubuntu-14.04, plesk, apache-modules

I'm using Plesk control panel on ubuntu 14.04.

I installed apache PHP module, then I got this error:

> Apache is running a threaded MPM, but your PHP Module is not compiled to be threadsafe. You need to recompile PHP.

So I tried uninstalling module with command:

```
apt-get remove libapache2-mod-php5
```

But I got another error:

> Syntax error on line 33 of /etc/apache2/plesk.conf.d/roundcube.conf:
>   Wrapper /var/www/cgi-bin/cgi_wrapper/cgi_wrapper cannot be accessed: (2)No such file or directory

How can  I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a known behavior. You need to bring libapache2-mod-php5 back and choose "Event" mode in `Tools & Settings > Apache Web Server > Apache modules > MPM mode`